# State Management in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, state

I've looked around on the internet for the solution to this but I still haven't found one that works. I've tried the following state management tools:

- useContext
- Redux
- Zustand
- Recoil

I want my NextJS site to update a value on each page when I click a simple button. Right now I'm using Recoil as I've found it one of the easiest state management tool so far.

This is my `_app.js`

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      < Component {...pageProps} />
    </RecoilRoot>
  )
}
```

This is `index.js`:

```
export default function Home() {
  const [city, setCity] = useRecoilState(cityState)
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{city}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCity("paris")}>click</button>
    </>
   );
}
```

This is page 2

```
export default function SecondPage() {
  const [city, setCity] = useRecoilState(cityState)
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{city}</h1>
    </>
   );
}
```

`./state/state.js`

```
export const cityState = atom({
    key: "cityState",
    default: "moscow"
})
```

When I click the change button on `index.js`, I simply want it to change for `SecondPage` and all pages where I reference the state stored in `state.js`. Right now it changes on `index.js` but `SecondPage` stays as "moscow". I want it to update when the button on index is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how your code structure is but I think your easiest option is React Context API. Let's give you an example for a better explanation;

Your Context script:

```
 import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const GlobalContext = createContext(); // you can set a default value inside createContext if you want


export default function ContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [city, setCity] = useState("moscow")

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={[city, setCity]}>
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Your `_app.js` file:

```
import ContextProvider from "your_directory"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      < Component {...pageProps} />
    </ContextProvider>
  )
}
```

`index.js` file:

```
    import ContextProvider, {GlobalContext} from 'your directory'

export default function Home() {
  const [city, setCity] = useContext(GlobalContext)
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{city}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCity("paris")}>click</button>
    </>
   );
}
```

Your script for Page 2:

```
import ContextProvider, {GlobalContext} from 'your directory'

export default function SecondPage() {
  const [city] = useContext(GlobalContext)

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{city}</h1>
    </>
   );
}
```

Comment: If local data, it is fine to wrap the provider around _app.js. however, if need to fetch data externally, we can't run getserversideprops or getstaticprops in _app.js isn't it?